# Phalcon relationships many to many, cannot query properly

Tags: php, database, many-to-many, phalcon

I'm new with PHP and MySQL. I'm building my own anime CMS on Cphalcon framework, but have some problems with relationships many to many, and cannot query properly.

I have 3 tables on MariaDB:

Anime:

```
id
title
slug
cover
```

Seasons:

```
id
name
animeId
```

Episodes:

```
id
animeId
seasonsId
name
cover
```

And 3 models from phalcon:

Anime:

```
<?php
namespace LearnPhalcon\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;


class Anime extends Model
{

  public $id;

  public $title;

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Seasons', 'animeId', [
        'alias' => 'seasons'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Episodes', 'animeId', [
        'alias' => 'episodes'
    ]);
  }

}
```

Seasons:

```
<?php
namespace LearnPhalcon\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;



class Seasons extends Model
{
  public $id;

  public $name;

  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->belongsTo('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Anime', 'id', [
        'alias' => 'anime'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Episodes', 'seasonsId', [
        'alias' => 'episodes'
    ]);
  }

}
```

Episodes:

```
<?php
namespace LearnPhalcon\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;


class Episodes extends Model
{
  public $id;

  public $name;


  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->belongsTo('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Anime', 'id', [
        'alias' => 'anime'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('id', __NAMESPACE__ . '\Seasons', 'id', [
        'alias' => 'seasons'
    ]);
  }

}
```

Action inside a index controller here:

```
public function aniAction($slug)
    {
      $slug = $this->dispatcher->getParam('slug');
      $ani = Anime::findFirst(array(
      'slug = :slug:',
      'bind' => array(
      'slug' => $slug
      )));


      if ($ani === false) {
       $this->dispatcher->forward(array(
         'controller' => 'Error',
         'action' => 'ops'
        ));
      }

     $this->view->setVar('ani', $ani);
     $this->view->setTemplateBefore('public');
    }
```

And the view:

```
  {% for seasons in ani.seasons %}
    {{ seasons.name }}
    <br/>
    {% for episodes in seasons.episodes %}
      {{ episodes.name }}
      <br/>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Actually the code works, but 
it returns only episodes on first season and not for each season

Example from db:

Anime:

```
 ID: 1
 Title: Test Anime
 Slug: test-anime
 Cover: /var/uploads/test.png
```

Seasons:

```
--------------------
     ID: 1
     Name: Season 1
     animeId: 1
--------------------
     ID: 2
     Name: Season 2
     animeId: 1
--------------------
```

Episodes:

```
--------------------
ID: 1
animeId: 1
seasonsId: 1
name: Test Name
cover: n/d
---------------------
ID: 2
animeId: 1
seasonsId: 1
name: Test Name2
cover: n/d
---------------------
ID: 3
animeId: 1
seasonsId: 2
name: Test Name3
cover: n/d
---------------------
```

From the actual test action I got this in HTML:

```
Season 1
Test Name
Test Name2
Season 2 
(and here nothing)
should be Test Name3?
```

Comment: The code looks good, and it's working.  I would look closer at the data - double check that Test Name3 is, in fact properly related to Season 2.

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking how to make many to many relationship

Anime:

```
$this->hasManyToMany('id',__NAMESPACE__ . '\Episodes','animeId','seasonsId',__NAMESPACE__ . '\Seasons','id',['alias'=>'Seasons']);
```

Seasons:

```
$this->hasManyToMany('id',__NAMESPACE__ . '\Episodes','seasonsId','animeId',__NAMESPACE__ . '\Anime','id',['alias'=>'Anime']);
```